# Find and replace in Word a referenced array from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, replace, ms-word

I wrote the following macro to scan through a PPT document and find/replace a range of words on a referenced excel sheet.  This works more or less exactly how I'd like it to.  I'm now attempting to set this up for use with Word documents as well, but am having some trouble with the "Word" syntax as it differs a bit.  Can anyone help me get started here?

Maybe there's a better way to do this - I wrote it in this manner because it allows any user to open the Excel document, click a button, pull up their document and have the macro do its work.

```
Sub QE_US()
    'VARIABLES
    Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.presentation
    Dim fnd As Variant
    Dim rplc As Variant
    Dim FindArray As Variant
    Dim ReplaceArray As Variant
    Dim TxtRng As PowerPoint.TextRange
    Dim TmpRng As PowerPoint.TextRange
    Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim objPPT As Object

    'PROMPT USER TO OPEN POWERPOINT DOC
    Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    objPPT.Visible = True

    AppActivate Application.Caption
    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Please Choose PowerPoint for QE - US Conversion")

    If strFileToOpen = False Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
        GoTo Ending
    End If

    objPPT.Presentations.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen

    'PULLING ARRAY FROM EXCEL
    FindArray = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Conversion").Range("C3:C64"))
    ReplaceArray = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Conversion").Range("B3:B64"))

    'LOOP THROUGH EACH SLIDE
    For Each sld In objPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides
        objPPT.Activate
        objPPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide sld.SlideIndex
        For y = LBound(FindArray) To UBound(FindArray)
            For Each shp In sld.Shapes
                fnd = FindArray(y)
                rplc = ReplaceArray(y)

                If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                    If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                        Set TxtRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(fnd, 0, True, WholeWords:=msoFalse)
                        If TxtRng Is Nothing Then GoTo NextTxtRng
                        TxtRng.Select

                        AppActivate Application.Caption
                        If MsgBox("Replace " & fnd & " with " & rplc & "?", vbYesNo + vbSystemModal) = vbYes _
                        Then Set TmpRng = TxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=fnd, _
                        ReplaceWhat:=rplc, WholeWords:=False, MatchCase:=True)
                    End If
                End If

                'REPLACE OTHER INSTANCES
                Do While Not TmpRng Is Nothing
                    Set TmpRng = TxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=fnd, _
                    ReplaceWhat:=rplc, WholeWords:=False, MatchCase:=False)
                Loop

                'IF TEXT RANGE IS NOTHING (NO VALUE FOUND)
NextTxtRng:
            Next shp
        Next y
    Next sld

    AppActivate Application.Caption
    MsgBox "QE replaced with US"

    'IF NO POWERPOINT SELECTED
Ending:
End Sub
```

I imagine it can be simplified quite a bit as it's no longer looking through slides, shapes, etc and can just scan the entire document?

Comment: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm

Comment: Thanks!  I actually was using this as a starting point and have it working for static text but can't figure out how to fit my arrays into `.Text` and `.Replacement.Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm as a starting point:

```
Sub ReplaceInWord()

    Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, c As Range

    wdApp.Visible = True

    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\twilliams\Desktop\test.docx")
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C64")
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            FindReplaceAnywhere wdDoc, c.Value, c.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    Next c

    wdDoc.Close True

End Sub

Public Sub FindReplaceAnywhere(doc As Word.Document, pFindTxt As String, pReplaceTxt As String)
  Dim rngStory As Word.Range
  Dim lngJunk As Long
  Dim oShp As Shape

  'Fix the skipped blank Header/Footer problem
  lngJunk = doc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType
  'Iterate through all story types in the current document
  For Each rngStory In doc.StoryRanges
    'Iterate through all linked stories
    Do
      SearchAndReplaceInStory rngStory, pFindTxt, pReplaceTxt
      On Error Resume Next
      Select Case rngStory.StoryType
      Case 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
        If rngStory.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
          For Each oShp In rngStory.ShapeRange
            If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
              SearchAndReplaceInStory oShp.TextFrame.TextRange, _
                  pFindTxt, pReplaceTxt
            End If
          Next
        End If
      Case Else
        'Do Nothing
      End Select
      On Error GoTo 0
      'Get next linked story (if any)
      Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
    Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
  Next
End Sub
Public Sub SearchAndReplaceInStory(ByVal rngStory As Word.Range, _
    ByVal strSearch As String, ByVal strReplace As String)
  With rngStory.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = strSearch
    .Replacement.Text = strReplace
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Below is the resulting working code.

```
Sub US_QE_Word()

'VARIABLES
Dim rngXL As Range
Dim x As Range
Dim strFind As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim rngStory As Object
Dim lngJunk As Long
Dim objWord As Object

'PROMPT USER TO OPEN DOC
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

AppActivate Application.Caption
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please Choose File for US - QE Conversion")

If strFileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No file selected."
    GoTo Ending
End If

objWord.Documents.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen

'FIND/REPLACE

objWord.ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True
Set rngXL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Range("B3:B80")

    For Each rngStory In objWord.ActiveDocument.StoryRanges

        For Each x In rngXL
          strFind = x.Value
            strReplace = x.Offset(0, 1).Value

      With rngStory.Find

         .Text = strFind
         .Replacement.Text = strReplace
         .Wrap = wdFindContinue
         .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

      End With

  Next
  Next


AppActivate Application.Caption
MsgBox ("US replaced with QE.  Please review changes.")

'IF NO FILE SELECTED
Ending:
End Sub
```